# Axis webservice jQuery call, results in error

Tags: java, web-services, jquery, axis

I created Axis webservice using Eclipse ( Indigo ), using AXIS default from new, other, webservice.  I have it running fine and accepting calls and returning data from the Ecplipse tester ( Webservice explorer ).  I have also consumed the WSDL in .net and called it from there and got data back without any probelms.

However I need to call it from jQuery, I'm using google CDN 1.7.1 reference.

When I call it like so

```
        // enables cross-site scripting in jQuery   
        jQuery.support.cors = true;

        var soapMessage =
            '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:q0="http://webservice.website.test.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                <q0:helloworld /> \
            </helloworld> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
            </soapenv:Envelope>';


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: this._baseURL + method,
    requestHeaders: "",
    data: soapMessage,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "xml",
    SOAPAction: this._baseURL + method,
    success: function(msg)
    { 
        alert(msg); 
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }

    });
    }
```

I used to get soapaction error back, I have added the soapaction and now I'm getting,
no SOAPAction header!

Btw, I'm on the same domain localhost, i set the cors just in case.

Any idea how to get it going in jQuery ? 
I have not update Axis to Axis2, would that be recommended ?

Comment: Refer this client http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient